# Convert DynamodB date format string to Date format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, amazon-dynamodb

Dynamo dB is storing a date in string format. For example:

> 1548005663900

How to convert back to original date format after getting date string data from dynamo dB using javascript?

`new Date("1548005663900")` is working only in the console and it is not working with Javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the timestamp string you are getting from your database as an integer to `new Date()`. For example:

```js
const timestamp = '1548005663900';
const dt = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));
console.log(dt);
```